# Function that extracts certain specified line of a text file in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

Was wondering if someone can help me with this. So I have a text file with 10 lines, a while loop and a counter that starts at 10. For each iteration of the loop, I will decrement it. However for every iteration, I want to extract a line say the 10th line on the first rotation and the 9th line on the second to compare them. Is there a function that say you pass a value to and it extracts a certain line? or some combination of it. Would appreciate the help 
Thanks

Comment: in Unix, there is a very useful mini-language called awk that lets you do these sort of things very easily; it takes little time to learn it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your line number to `awk`:

If you have the line number in variable `i` then:

`val=$(awk -v line=$i 'NR==line{print;exit}' filename)`

will store the `i`th line into variable `val`.

Comment: small effiecency: `awk -v line=$i 'NR==line{print;exit}'`

Comment: Thanks! I am trying this out right now, how can i check that this worked? i keep doing echo $val, however it just shows me a blank line?

Comment: @Masterminder Do you set some value to `i` ? and `i` th line exists in the file? If so, `echo $val` should give that line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with tail and head:

```
line=$(tail -n "+$N" file | head -n 1)
```

`tail -n "+$N" file` will print file starting from the line number `$N`, and `head -n 1` will print the first line it receives from tail. The final result will then be stored in the variable `$line` (without the ending newline character).

If you want something shorter, there's a sed oneliner:

```
line=$(sed -n -e "$N { p; q }" file)
```

which will call the print "p" command only on the line number `$N`, and then quit with the quit "q" command.

EDIT: Added `q` command as suggested by *glenn jackman* on comment for another answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in a shell :

```
read -p "Give me the number of the wanted line >>> "
sed -n "${REPLY}{p;q}" FILE
```

Comment: small efficiency: `sed -n "${REPLY}{p;q}"`

Comment: which variable do i increase by 1 to extract the next line?

Comment: `c=22; ((c++)); sed -n "${c}{p;q}" FILE` (in bash)